# List/Tuples to Dictionaries. How to stack data instead substitute them?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, data-structures, tuples

I have the source data like:

```
   source= [['data1', 'foo'],   
      ['data2', 'bar'],
      ['data3', 'ddd1'],
      ['data2', 'ddd2'],
      ['data2', 'new'],
      ['data1', 'data']]
```

Of course I can  `dict(key,value) for key,value in source`, but that will give me `data1: data`, `data2: new` and `data3: ddd1`. While what I'm looking for is: `data1: [ 'foo', 'data' ]`, `data2: ['bar', 'ddd2']` and `data3: [ 'ddd1' ]`, is there any method that can do that?

Comment: I'm curious why the -1.

Comment: When you hover over the downvote button, it says `This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful`.  I believe the part before the semicolon fits well.  I just did a quick search.  My first query was `python list to dictionary appending to already-used keys`.  The second result had the answer.  It isn't the only one, however.  The one found by Martijn is a different one.

Comment: Hi Zondo, thank you for the reply, unfortunately I haven used these words. I used words like stack. My bad. But yes, I have researched for a solution (during sometime) before post here. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) class:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> source= [['data1', 'foo'],   
...       ['data2', 'bar'],
...       ['data3', 'ddd1'],
...       ['data2', 'ddd2'],
...       ['data2', 'new'],
...       ['data1', 'data']]
...
>>> for k,v in source:
...     d[k].append(v)
...
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'data1': ['foo', 'data'], 'data2': ['bar', 'ddd2', 'new'], 'data3': ['ddd1']})
```